# Heroku code=H10 desc="App crashed" - Can't figure out why it's crashing

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I've been searching around on this one for a while and can't find anything that seems to be applicable in my situation. I've been staring at these logs and I can't see what the problem is.

This has happened during deployments before, but always seemed to resolve itself. Now this just happened on its own (no deployment) and I can't get out of it. Tried reverting back to a previous version of the app, but it appears I'm stuck. I've reset the dyno and have also done a rake db:migrate.

There are some repetitive things in the log, but I just don't know what to read out of them. Anybody have any idea where the problem is? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. See the logs below.

```
Jun 18 15:51:54 snapclass-production app/heroku-postgres:  source=HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_WHITE measure.current_transaction=1077 measure.db_size=6153016bytes measure.tables=0 measure.active-connections=3 measure.waiting-connections=0 measure.index-cache-hit-rate=0.99981 measure.table-cache-hit-rate=0.99349
Jun 18 15:52:06 snapclass-production heroku/router:  at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.snapclass.com fwd="46.165.195.139" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= 
Jun 18 15:52:07 snapclass-production heroku/router:  at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.snapclass.com fwd="178.255.152.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= 
Jun 18 15:52:12 snapclass-production app/postgres:  [47-1]  [] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time 
Jun 18 15:52:13 snapclass-production app/postgres:  [48-1]  [] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 0 buffers (0.0%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.000 s, sync=0.000 s, total=0.334 s; sync files=0, longest=0.000 s, average=0.000 s 
Jun 18 15:52:51 snapclass-production app/heroku-postgres:  source=HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_WHITE measure.current_transaction=1077 measure.db_size=6153016bytes measure.tables=0 measure.active-connections=3 measure.waiting-connections=0 measure.index-cache-hit-rate=0.99994 measure.table-cache-hit-rate=0.99997 
Jun 18 15:53:06 snapclass-production heroku/router:  at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.snapclass.com fwd="95.141.32.46" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= 
Jun 18 15:53:48 snapclass-production app/heroku-postgres:  source=HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_WHITE measure.current_transaction=1077 measure.db_size=6153016bytes measure.tables=0 measure.active-connections=3 measure.waiting-connections=0 measure.index-cache-hit-rate=0.97826 measure.table-cache-hit-rate=0.99999 
Jun 18 15:54:06 snapclass-production heroku/router:  at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.snapclass.com fwd="95.211.217.68" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= 
Jun 18 15:54:17 snapclass-production heroku/router:  at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.snapclass.com fwd="205.197.158.210" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= 
Jun 18 15:54:17 snapclass-production heroku/router:  at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=www.snapclass.com fwd="205.197.158.210" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= 
Jun 18 15:54:25 snapclass-production heroku/router:  at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=demosidney.snapclass.com fwd="202.46.61.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=  
Jun 18 15:54:44 snapclass-production heroku/web.1:  State changed from crashed to starting 
Jun 18 15:54:44 snapclass-production app/heroku-postgres:  source=HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_WHITE measure.current_transaction=1077 measure.db_size=6153016bytes measure.tables=0 measure.active-connections=3 measure.waiting-connections=0 measure.index-cache-hit-rate=0.98897 measure.table-cache-hit-rate=0.99087 
Jun 18 15:54:48 snapclass-production heroku/web.1:  Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RAILS_ENV -p 50180` 
Jun 18 15:55:40 snapclass-production app/heroku-postgres:  source=HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_WHITE measure.current_transaction=1077 measure.db_size=6153016bytes measure.tables=0 measure.active-connections=3 measure.waiting-connections=0 measure.index-cache-hit-rate=0.99926 measure.table-cache-hit-rate=0.99996 
Jun 18 15:55:50 snapclass-production heroku/web.1:  Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch 
Jun 18 15:55:50 snapclass-production heroku/web.1:  Stopping process with SIGKILL 
Jun 18 15:55:51 snapclass-production heroku/web.1:  Process exited with status 137 
Jun 18 15:55:51 snapclass-production heroku/web.1:  State changed from starting to crashed 
Jun 18 15:55:52 snapclass-production heroku/router:  at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=demosidney.snapclass.com fwd="119.63.193.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= 
Jun 18 15:55:52 snapclass-production heroku/router:  at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/snapclasses/sat-prep-math/register host=www.snapclass.com fwd="173.199.115.115" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= 
Jun 18 15:55:53 snapclass-production heroku/router:  at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.snapclass.com fwd="23.21.36.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= 
Jun 18 15:55:54 snapclass-production heroku/router:  at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.snapclass.com fwd="23.22.98.102" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= 
Jun 18 15:55:54 snapclass-production heroku/router:  at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.snapclass.com fwd="91.109.115.41" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= 
Jun 18 15:56:06 snapclass-production heroku/router:  at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.snapclass.com fwd="174.34.224.167" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: Have you tried contacting heroku's support?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a good way to reach their support team anymore. I only see a page for a [Critical Support service](https://www.heroku.com/critical). Most everything directs back to their [Help](https://help.heroku.com/) docs. You used to be able to submit a ticket, but not it looks like the Critical Support is some added service. So I have gone through their docs for some help and come up empty, but haven't contacted their critical support.

Comment: Check if this solution will work for you [package.json misconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17180495/heroku-code-h10-desc-app-crashed-cant-figure-out-why-its-crashing/58679162#58679162)

Answer (score 32):

Try following steps:

```
- git push heroku master # if not done
- heroku run rake db:migrate
- heroku restart
```

Wait couple of minutes...

Comment: `heroku restart` was what fixed it for my PHP app. Thanks!

Comment: `heroku restart` instantly fixed my Sinatra App. Thank you very much.

Comment: this worked! thanks for sharing.

- heroku run rake db:migrate
- heroku restart

Answer (score 20):

In my case it was because I was hardcoding the port to be used,

I changed using this, and it worked

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Answer (score 7):

To create a heroku account

```
 $heroku create
```

To verify your git configration is well

```
$git remote -v
```

Associate a Git repo with an existing application

```
$heroku git:remote -a herokuapp-name
```

To perform push to master

```
$git push heroku master
```

To get your database to work you will have to migrate to production database

```
$heroku run bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Then restart

```
heroku restart
```

finaly browse to your location

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced this error, overall this error means that It can't work with your dependencies and one of the reason may be old versions of dependencies. I solved this by following two steps:
1) I updated all my dependencies manually.
2) I changed my Flask API from app.py to err.py (could be helpful to have different name, but not necessary.

This worked for me.
Hope, it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the main entry in `package.json` pointing at the wrong directory. Ensure it is pointed to the build output directory. As for my case, I had the server file in the */bin* folder so I set my `package.json`

```
{
  "main": "build/bin/www.js"
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ."
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was working with express on ES6 using babel, the babel was imported as devDependency (**Heroku ignores devDependencies in production**) after including them into dependencies it worked for me.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/register": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.4"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

changing how I connect to my database on code helped

```
    let  databaseURL = pgURL
   if var postgresConfig = PostgresConfiguration(url: databaseURL) {
    postgresConfig.tlsConfiguration = tls
    app.databases.use(.postgres(
        configuration: postgresConfig
    ), as: .psql)
    app.middleware.use(ErrorMiddleware.default(environment: app.environment))

    app.migrations.add(CreateTranscription())
    app.migrations.add(CreateTemplate())

    app.routes.defaultMaxBodySize = "10mb"

    try app.autoMigrate().wait()

    // register routes
    try routes(app)
} else{
    fatalError("DATABASE_URL not configured")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setup Proc file in your App

```
web: node build/build.js
```

[Heroku Proc file](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile)