# heroku run rake db:migrate - /bin/sh: 1: rake: not found

Tags: python, ruby, heroku, migration, rake

When I am trying to run `heroku run rake db:migrate` from [Heroku code=H10 desc="App crashed" - Can't figure out why it's crashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17180495/heroku-code-h10-desc-app-crashed-cant-figure-out-why-its-crashing) I get `/bin/sh: 1: rake: not found`

```
- git push heroku master # if not done
- heroku run rake db:migrate
- heroku restart
```

Any suggestions?

Logs of the command:

```
2017-07-08T23:10:22.242114+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `rake db:migrate` by user myname@gmail.com
2017-07-08T23:10:36.592694+00:00 heroku[run.1110]: Awaiting client
2017-07-08T23:10:36.631698+00:00 heroku[run.1110]: Starting process with command `rake db:migrate`
2017-07-08T23:10:36.728622+00:00 heroku[run.1110]: State changed from starting to up
2017-07-08T23:10:41.467500+00:00 heroku[run.1110]: State changed from up to complete
2017-07-08T23:10:41.454044+00:00 heroku[run.1110]: Process exited with status 127
```

Comment: Do you have the logs of the command?

Comment: why are you tagging this with python and ruby? Can you show the output of `heroku run ls`?

Comment: `heroku run ls --app nameofmyapp` returns `Dockerfile  nameofmyapp  docker-compose.yml  init.sql  requirements.txt`

Comment: Is everything working fine in your development mode? Can you try following command - heroku run rails c 
Usually upon running console, it gives detailed output.

Comment: In both cases `heroku run rails c` and `heroku run rails` I get `Couldn't find that app.`