# "How to fix 'App crashed' on heroku in cmd prompt"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, logging, cmd

I am trying to launch my app on heroku. Yet when I execute `heroku open` command I see that it is giving an issue in the logs that "App crashed"

Tried checking logs and restarting rails server.

`heroku logs --app obscure-beyond-78036`

> CMD

2019-10-08T19:49:11.686542+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=obscure-beyond-78036.herokuapp.com request_id=db281cf3-6b5b-46fa-b35d-72617b23a864 fwd="73.244.194.180" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Expected functionality is to launch the app on heroku.

Added logs

```
C:\r5.1>heroku logs --app obscure-beyond-78036
2019-11-09T22:31:51.129452+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-11-09T22:31:56.935810+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 32098 -e production`
2019-11-09T22:31:59.364804+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-11-09T22:31:59.370115+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-11-09T22:31:59.344842+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2019-11-09T22:31:59.274991+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’: No such file or directory
2019-11-09T22:32:03.221294+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 37912 -e production`
2019-11-09T22:32:05.568964+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-11-09T22:32:05.551998+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2019-11-09T22:32:05.470297+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please add the entire log output to your question. What you provided is just a standard error that doesn't provide any information about what may be causing the app to crash.

Comment: @MarkMerritt that is the entire log I get.

Comment: Have you tried `$ heroku restart`?

Comment: @MarkMerritt let me try that.

Comment: `$ heroku restart`
 »   Error: Missing required flag:
 »     -a, --app APP  app to run command against
 »   See more help with --help

Answer (score 1):

Check out docs about logs and how to work with them on Heroku 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log-retrieval
and ask again if the logs are not clear to you.

Also, a google search shows some typical issues with rails app on heroku, for example [Heroku code=H10 desc="App crashed" - Can't figure out why it's crashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17180495/heroku-code-h10-desc-app-crashed-cant-figure-out-why-its-crashing)